# Multidimensional Slices in Go

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, go, slice

I would like to have an array / slice in Go with a variadic number of elements (not known at compile time) and be able to dinamically add new elements of different types, for instance:

```
data[0] := "string"
data[1] // slice 
data[1][0] := "another string"
data[1][1] := 42 // int
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit ugly but possible using empty interfaces, `interface{}`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    variadic := []interface{}{}

    variadic = append(variadic, "foo")
    variadic = append(variadic, []interface{}{"bar", 42})

//this will print "foo"
    fmt.Println(variadic[0])

    //note that you have to cast variadic[1] to an array before accessing it
    fmt.Println(variadic[1].([]interface{})[0])

}
```

If you allow the assumption that each element must be an array of anything with varying length, it's a bit less ugly:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

        variadic := [][]interface{}{}

        variadic = append(variadic, []interface{}{"foo"})
        variadic = append(variadic, []interface{}{"bar", 42})


        fmt.Println(variadic[0])
        fmt.Println(variadic[1][0])
        fmt.Println(variadic[1][1])

    }
```

Comment: Ugly indeed, but I guess it does the job. Thanks!

Comment: The second example is only good iff dealing with 2 dimensions, otherwise it gets ugly as well: http://play.golang.org/p/Is2Av34sUs